# Android HttpResponseCache, can i use that cache data?

Tags: android, caching, httpresponse

i searched the web for this but was unable to find an answer.

I use HttpResponeCache to cache the response from my http request.
But i want my app, if no internet is available and the file still exists, to use that cache.

The caching:

```
private void enableHttpResponseCache(File cacheDir) {
    try {
        long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB 
        File httpCacheDir = new File(cacheDir, "http");
        Class.forName("android.net.http.HttpResponseCache")
                .getMethod("install", File.class, long.class)
                .invoke(null, httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
    } catch (Exception httpResponseCacheNotAvailable) {
    }
}
```

I looked into the files that the function had created, there are 3 files:

- e8b34557a3241feb7e186d1b86c9af4c.0
- e8b34557a3241feb7e186d1b86c9af4c.1
- journal

And the file e8b34557a3241feb7e186d1b86c9af4c.1 does contain my JSON data.

So is there a way to get and use that data?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) of `HTTPResponseCache`. You can force a cache response!

```
//....
try {
     connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached");
     InputStream cached = connection.getInputStream();
     // the resource was cached! show it
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     // the resource was not cached 
 }
```